# How to send unique messages daily via Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

So I have a newsletter, but I'm having trouble coming up with a way to track Quotes that have been sent. I'd like to track sent quotes to avoid sending duplicates.

The app is quite simple, there's a quote model that belongs_to category model, and a subscriber model that belongs to a category model. A category has_many subscribers and quotes.

The code below sends the first Quote to its subscriber. Of course You have to maintain a table or a field that keeps of track of what quotes were sent earlier to the subscriber so you can always manage to send a new quote every day.

```
Category.all.each do |category|
   category.subscribers.each do |subscriber|
      SubscriptionMailer.sendmyemail(subscriber.email, category, category.quotes.first.body, category.subscribers).deliver          
   end
end
```

This can further be updated to:

```
Category.all.each do |category|
   category.subscribers.each do |subscriber|
      SubscriptionMailer.sendmyemail(subscriber.email, category, subscriber.choose_quote(category), category.subscribers).deliver          
   end
end
```

And in my subscriber.rb model I have this method ready, but not sure what code to fill it with to achieve what I want. How can I send a quote to subscribers once a day which is unique and not a duplicate of what's been sent in the past? Or maybe even an easier way would be to randomize the order, is this possible?

```
def choose_quote(cat)
  # send quote which is unique 
  # Meaning which was not sent 
end
```

Comment: You can save the history in separate table, when which quote has been send to the user after each quote has been send.

Comment: Care to provide an example of this? ty

Comment: Sure. Let me write an answer.

Comment: I have provided my suggested model for your problem. Hope you review it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Your are sending quotes to your subscribers
- You need to track which quotes has been sent to your user.

I would suggest a possible solution design for that specific problem you mentioned.

```
rails generate model quote_history subscriber:references quote:references # assumed there
#is a model subscriber and quote
```

So now subscriber_quote_history will belongs to subscribers and quotes as well.

```
class QuoteHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscriber
  belongs_to :quote
  validates :quote_id, :uniqueness => {scope: :subscriber_id}
end
```

So both subscriber, quote should have many quote_histories has they have been sent.

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :quote_histories
   .....
end

class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :quote_histories
   scope :uniq_quote_for, Proc.new {|subscriber_id| includes(:quote_histories).where.not(quote_history: {subscriber_id: subscriber_id})}
   .....
end
```

Now I would suggest you to write some condition in your desired method:

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
 def choose_quote(cat)
   quote = cat.quotes.uniq_quote_for(self.id).order("RANDOM()").first #Add a new history after that for that. here you will decide your own business logic.
   return quote if self.quote_histories.create(qoute_id: quote.id)
   return nil
 end
end
```

In your mailer do something similar:

```
Category.all.each do |category|
   category.subscribers.each do |subscriber|
      quote = subscriber.choose_quote(category)
      if quote  # if quote found then send email
       SubscriptionMailer.sendmyemail(subscriber.email, category, quote, category.subscribers).deliver    
      else
        next # if no quote found then go to next loop.
      end      
   end
end
```

I believe this will help you to design your solution. Please note, I wrote here everything from visualization and from my own logic. Please skip some unwanted conventional errors or anything. My intention here is to just show you the way to sort your problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This is great, can you specify what would go into the find method in the last line i.e: Quote.uniq_quote_for(self.id).find(....) and I will accept your answer.

Comment: That depends on your business logic. Are you gonna send one quote per mail ?

Comment: Also let me know if the association between quote and category.

Comment: I'm going to send one quote a day per subscriber. So each subscriber, will receive one NEW quote each day. And a quote belongs to a category, and a category has many quotes.

Comment: Okey, I will write you the full solution soon. I am unavailable riht now. But u can try it in the meanwhile.

Comment: Perhaps I could do find(:first, :order => 'RAND()') ? not sure if this syntax is correct.

Comment: well just Quote.order('RANDOM()').first will do that :) I have specified. Also I add to add a history after each quote is send.

Comment: I have completed my answer will everything. Just try to do little bit refactor on that. That will work! :)

Comment: Thank you this is awesome! Although getting one error when running rake db:migrate, /quote.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '|'
  scope :uniq_quote_for, -> {|subscriber_id| includes(:quot...

Comment: please check if there is any syntax error.  Oh also I apologize. Please replace -> {|subscriber_id|} with Proc.new {|subscriber_id|}

Comment: There seems to be just one last error when I run the SubscriptionMailer.sendmyemail method I get the following: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "quote_history"
LINE 1: ...otes"."id" WHERE "quotes"."category_id" = $1 AND ("quote_his...                                                      
: SELECT  DISTINCT "quotes"."id", RANDOM() AS alias_0 FROM "quotes" LEFT OUTER JOIN "quote_histories" ON "quote_histories"."quote_id" = "quotes"."id" WHERE "quotes"."category_id" = $1 AND ("quote_history"."subscriber_id" != 12)

Comment: ohho did you run the migration? after generating models? if you need more help you can add me on skype so I can help directly. skype: rorxpert